# downloading latest vagrant box with virtualbox

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

We are downloading vagrant box using below command. But it is tied to a specific version.

wget https://vagrantcloud.com/generic/boxes/centos7/versions/**1.9.28**/providers/virtualbox.box

Is there any way or command in which I can get latest version of the box. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Hi there!
If my answer was useful please remember to upvote it / mark it as final answer.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you are looking for:

```
vagrant box update
```

Here is also [its documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/cli/box.html#box-update) and a quick reference (be sure to read the part in **bold**):

> Box Update Command: vagrant box update
>
> This command updates the box for the current Vagrant environment if
>   there are updates available. The command can also update a specific
>   box (outside of an active Vagrant environment), by specifying the
>   --box flag.
>
> Note that updating the box will not update an already-running Vagrant
>   machine. To reflect the changes in the box, **you will have to destroy
>   and bring back up the Vagrant machine**.
>
> If you just want to check if there are updates available, use the
>   vagrant box outdated command.

Comment: Hi @user872274, if my answer was useful for you please consider upvoting it and/or choosing it as final answer. Thanks!